# Store redux-form's dirty prop in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

In my current application I see that [anyTouched](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/props.md/#-code-anytouched-boolean-code-) prop is already present in the redux store for all the redux forms I have in my web application.

I want to store [dirty](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/props.md/#-code-dirty-boolean-code-) prop for all those forms in the redux store, so I can access it in the other part of the web application such as navigation bar.

I have tried [isDirty](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/selectors.md/#-code-isdirty-formname-string-code-returns-code-state-fields-string-gt-dirty-boolean-code-) selector. It was displaying empty value. According to the selector's documentation - selectors may be used in any part of your application to query the state of any of your forms. Sadly, it didn't work for me.

In my current code I couldn't find how [anyTouched](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/props.md/#-code-anytouched-boolean-code-) got stored in the redux store in the first place :-(.

My question is what do I need to do to store dirty prop in redux store?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take only dirty value from the `redux-form` instead of `isDirty` you can also use `loadash` this javaScript code which I use to get the only dirty value while submiting the form.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

render() {
    const { intl } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <UserForm
          initialValues={this.initializeData()}
          intl={intl}
          onSubmit={immutableValues => {
            const data = immutableValues.toJS();
            this.getDirtyData(data);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

initializeData() {
    ... Whatever your initialize data
}

getDirtyData(immutableData) {
      // Dirty data
      const updatedObj = this.changes(immutableData, this.state.myInitialState); 
      //Here you will get your dirty data in updatedObj.         
  }

changes(object, base) {
    return _.transform(object, (result, value, key) => {
      if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) {
        result[key] =
          _.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])
            ? changes(value, base[key])
            : value;
      }
    });
  }
```

you will get the reference from https://gist.github.com/Yimiprod/7ee176597fef230d1451